# Files erased from vue project in vscode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

yesterday, the app I'm building was working fine. I went to bed, got up this morning and everything is broken.

-Vetur is uninstalled
-I can't write to file because I don't have access
-my "footer" component is there, but all the code was erased
-the router/index.js file is there but has no more code

I got the files back from my backup, reinstalled vetur and somehow managed to get acces back.
I haven't  worked in the footer file for days. there is nothing in there. just a few lines of code. I didn't edit the package?json file either...

I scanned for viruses but found nothing. I'm kinda freaking out a bit.

Anybody knows what might be going on?

thanks in advance!

Eric

Comment: That is where Github comes for a rescue. You should always commit your work before going to bed. 

Comment: Yeah I know. I tried learning how to use it but I just get so confused. I watched tons of tutorials but I was still beguining in coding and these tutorials are always for coders that know everything EXCEPT git and github. That was 8 months ago and couldnt figure out how to organise my wok in it. I might give it another go now that things are getting sketchy